# Commutative algebras associated to simple Lie algebras

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, lie-algebras, gap

In Section 2 of the article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869307000385, the authors study the center $Z=Z_Q$ of certain preprojective like algebras associated to the simply laced Dynkin quivers/simple Lie algebras and show that the dimension of the center is equal to the number of roots of the simple Lie algebra. My knowledge of this stuff is very limited and Im not sure whether there is more research on this topic.

> Question 1: Are explicit quiver and relations known for the centers $Z_Q$ associated to the simple Lie algebra?

In type $A_n$, the relations are very easy: $Z_{A_n}=k[x,y]/(p_n(x,y))$ , where $p_n(x,y)$ are all homogenous monomial of degree $n$. For example $Z_{A_3}=k[x,y]/(x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3)$.

> Question 1.5: Since those algebras have a Dynkin type classification, it seems likely that they come from another classification problem from homological algebra/representation theory. Is something in this direction known? Did they appear elsewhere?

In type $A_n$ the natural basis $e_i$ of $Z_{A_n}$ realises the root poset via the poset of submodules of the form $e_i Z_{A_n}$.
For example for $n=3$ and $B:=Z_{A_3}$ those modules are $B$, $xB$, $yB$, $x^2B$, $y^2B$, $xyB$.

> Question 2: Is there such a natural basis $e_i$ in the other Dynkin types too such that the submodule lattice realises the root poset?

Those algebras are over $\mathbb{C}$ and thus one can not calculate their quiver and relations using the GAP package QPA (or is there a trick to calculate quiver and relations at least over the rationals for centers of quiver algebras using QPA?).

But here is the quiver and relations of Dynkin type $D_4$ over the finite field with 17 elements (the field should probably have high enough characteristic to cause no problems) directly from the QPA output:
$Z_{D_4}=K[a1,a2,a3]/I$, where

`I=[ (Z(17)^0)*a2^2+(Z(17)^10)a3^2+(Z(17)^7)a1^2a2+(Z(17)^0)a1^2a3, (Z(17)^0)a1a2^2, (Z(17)^0)a1a2a3, (Z(17)^0)a1a3^2, (Z(17)^0)*a2^3,
(Z(17)^0)a2^2a3, (Z(17)^0)a2a3^2, (Z(17)^0)*a3^3, (Z(17)^3)*a2^2+(Z(17)^12)a2a3+(Z(17)^0)*a3^2+(Z(17))a1^2a2+(Z(17)^0)*a1^4, (Z(17)^0)a1^3a2 ]`

Of course those relations do not need to be in an optimal way. One might expect that there are "type $D_n$" versions of the homogeneous monomial polynomials that give the relations in that case. Are there any good candidates for such polynomials (that might even exist in types like $G_2, F_4 , B_n$ etc.) ? A good presentation of $I$ might be also key to find a canonical/good basis of $Z_Q$.

I was not able yet to find a "canonical" basis of $Z_{D_4}$ that realises the root poset. But $Z_{D_4}$ has 4-dimensional socle and that fits with the fact that the root poset of $D_4$ has 4 minimal elements.

> Question 3: Is there such a canonical basis at least for $D_4$ and what does it look like?

Assume we have a canonical basis (as in type $A_n$) and let $M$ be the direct sum of all submodules $e_i Z_Q$. Let $C_Q:=End_{Z_Q}(M)$.

> Question 4: Is it true that $C_Q$ has finite global dimension? What is the global dimension in that case?

I am especially interested in Dynkin type $A_n$. Here the basic version of $M$ is given by choosing one submodule of each dimension. I can show that $C_{A_n}$ at least has Cartan determinant equal to one, so it seems likely that it has finite global dimension. For $n=2$, the global dimension is 2, for $n=3$ and $n=4$ it was 3.
Furthermore in type $A_n$ the algebra $C_Q$ was even a quasi-hereditary quadratic algebra for $n=2,3,4$. I guess it might even be Koszul.

> Question 5: Is $C_{Q}$ for $Q=A_n$ a quasi-hereditary Koszul algebra?

Here quiver and relations for $C_{A_3}$:

`Quiver( ["v1","v2","v3"], [["v1","v2","a1"],["v1","v2","a2"],["v2","v1","a3"],["v2","v3","a4"],["v2","v3","a5"],["v3","v2","a6"]] )
[ (Z(17)^0)a1a3, (Z(17)^0)a2a3, (Z(17)^8)a1a5+(Z(17)^0)a2a4, (Z(17)^8)a3a1+(Z(17)^0)a4a6, (Z(17)^8)a3a2+(Z(17)^0)a5a6 ]`